# Связь в таблице

Tags: php, mysql

У меня есть две таблицы в БД. Мне нужно во второй таблице в поле routes_route_id сослаться на поле route_id в первой таблице, но я не могу указать связь на не ключевой атрибут. Как мне можно это сделать, подскажите пожалуйста.

Первая Routes:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вторая Trips: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да, связи с неключевым атрибутом быть не может. Ссылаться надо только на ключ. В данном случае если вы сошлетесь на id то вы получите ссылку на ту же самую запись, в которой лежит нужный вам route_id, если он там уникален конечно. А если вдруг route_id там не уникален, то и ссылки быть не может потому что ссылка должна ссылаться строго на одну запись

Comment: Да, route_id не уникален. У меня первая таблица заполнена следующим образом (1, 1, 1;   2, 1, 2;   3, 1, 3;)
Мне вот как раз и нужно связать их. Второе число это маршрут и в одном маршруте есть несколько станций. 
Понимаете о чём я?

Comment: Единственным назначением ссылки, т.е. ограничения внешнего ключа является обеспечение целостности БД. Она проверяет, что конкретная запись, на которую ведет ссылка действительно существует. По этой причине сама суть внешних ключей не предусматривает ссылок на несколько записей одновременно. Если вам это вдруг понадобилось, значит вы пытаетесь ссылаться не на ту таблицу

Comment: Вы хотите сослаться на конкретную станцию конкретного маршрута - тогда ссылайтесь на id. А если на маршрут в целом, то должна быть третья таблица, в которой этот route_id будет первичным ключем

Comment: Я понял. Наверное лучшим решение будет сделать связь многие-ко-многим между этими таблицами?

Comment: Понятия "связь между таблицами" не существует. Связь между конкретными записями этих таблиц. И что именно использовать зависит от физической природы этих отношений. Вы не описали в вопросе что из себя представляет вторая таблица, что именно она описывает. А значит и сказать что с чем связывать невозможно

Comment: Вторая таблица отвечает за конкретную поездку. 

Например поездка из точки А в точку Б. К этой поездке привязан конкретный маршрут. Но из точки А в точку Б может быть несколько маршрутов (через разные города).

Comment: Маршрут привязан целиком ? т.е. если маршрут проходит через станции A, Б, В. То поездка это всегда именно из А в В или она может использовать часть маршрута (А-Б) ?

Comment: Поездка из одного города в другой.
Но добраться в эти города можно по нескольким маршрутам. Вот у меня поле в таблице Trips должно ссылаться на определённый маршрут. А во второй таблице маршрут 1 это из города А в город Б, но проходит через одни станции, а маршрут 2 это из того же города А в город Б , но проходит через другие станции.

Comment: Тогда у вас в модели не хватает таблицы "маршруты". Таблица, которую вы назвали routes по сути является таблицей "станции маршрута". У вас должна быть еще одна таблица, в которой этот route_id будет первичным ключом (возможно кроме ключа в ней ничего и не будет, а возможно вы захотите хранить в ней чисто информационно текстовое представление маршрута или его писание). И тогда та, таблица, которая у вас сейчас routes должна будет на нее ссылаться своим route_id и таблица trips так же будет ссылаться на ту таблицу "маршруты"

Comment: И лично я бы в таблице "станции маршрута" не делал суррогатного id. А сделал бы первичным ключом связку из полей route_id и order

Comment: Спасибо за уделённое время)